# count frequencies in the values of dictionary in python

Tags: python

I want to create a dictionary from the following dictionary which takes all the values in each round and make it as index and store its frequency across rounds

I am maintaining a dictionary which gets bigger in every iteration

```
list_chosen_each_round  {0: ['1', '26', '20', '14', '28', '23'], 1: Index(['4', '17', '29', '21', '8', '11'], dtype='object', name='ID'), 2: Index(['11', '9', '3', '1', '27', '28'], dtype='object', name='ID')}
```

output should be like following:

```
'1': 2
'26': 1 
'20': 1
'14': 1
'28': 2
'23': 1
'4': 1
'17': 1
'29': 1
'21': 1
'8': 1
'11': 2
'9': 1
'3': 1
'27': 1
```

I used the following code

```
from collections import Counter
all_selections = sum(list_chosen_each_round.values(), [])
frequency_counter = Counter(all_selections)
print('frequency_counter ',frequency_counter)
```

It works well for the first round and it gives the correct output as follows

```
frequency_counter  Counter({'28': 1, '9': 1, '4': 1, '22': 1, '15': 1, '12': 1})
```

But after first round it gives

```
frequency_counter Counter({'2820': 1, '923': 1, '419': 1, '225': 1, '1517': 1, '1221': 1})
```

Why does it concatenate the index rather than making the new indices?

the above output should have been like following

```
frequency_counter Counter({'28': 1, '9': 1, '4': 1, '2': 1, '15': 1, '12': 1, '20': 1, '23': 1, '19': 1, '5': 1, '17': 1, '21': 1})
```

and if the index repeated the counter should have increased for that index

Comment: What is `Index`? It looks like Pandas Index. Why value for 0 is not `Index`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.chain` to flat your lists of list (or a nested comprehension)

```
from itertools import chain
frequency_counter = Counter(chain(*[lst for lst in list_chosen_each_round.values()]))

# OR

frequency_counter = Counter(item for lst in list_chosen_each_round.values()
                            for item in lst)
```

Output:

```
>>> frequency_counter
Counter({'1': 2,
         '28': 2,
         '11': 2,
         '26': 1,
         '20': 1,
         '14': 1,
         '23': 1,
         '4': 1,
         '17': 1,
         '29': 1,
         '21': 1,
         '8': 1,
         '9': 1,
         '3': 1,
         '27': 1})
```

If order matters, you have to handle the counter manually:

```
frequency_counter = {}
for lst in list_chosen_each_round.values():
    for item in lst:
        frequency_counter[item] = frequency_counter.get(item, 0) + 1
```

Output:

```
>>> frequency_counter
{'1': 2,
 '26': 1,
 '20': 1,
 '14': 1,
 '28': 2,
 '23': 1,
 '4': 1,
 '17': 1,
 '29': 1,
 '21': 1,
 '8': 1,
 '11': 2,
 '9': 1,
 '3': 1,
 '27': 1}
```